# MS Access Populate a form from pass-through query

Tags: ms-access, recordset, pass-through

I suspect this is a simple syntax issue, but I'm stuck.

I have this function:

```
Function CreateSPT(SPTQueryName As String, SQLString As String, _
              ConnectString As String)

Dim mydatabase As Database, myquerydef As QueryDef, MyRS  As Recordset

Set mydatabase = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)
Set myquerydef = mydatabase.CreateQueryDef(SPTQueryName)

myquerydef.Connect = ConnectString
myquerydef.SQL = SQLString
myquerydef.ReturnsRecords = False

myquerydef.ReturnsRecords = True
Set MyRS = myquerydef.OpenRecordset()
'MyRS.MoveFirst
DoCmd.OpenQuery SPTQueryName, acViewNormal, acReadOnly
myquerydef.Close End Function
```

When a button is pressed on my Form this is called.

```
Private Sub Btn_Search_Click()
If Not IsNull(DLookup("[AccessionNumber]", "[SA2001]", "[AccessionNumber] = '" & [Forms]![SA2001]![Txt_LabEpNo] & "'")) Then
    'MsgBox "Found"
    'Populates the form as required
    'I've removed the code as it's messy

Else
    'MsgBox "Not Found"
    Me.Refresh

    Dim SPTQueryName As String
    Dim SQLString As String
    Dim ConnectString As String

    DoCmd.Close acQuery, "XQuery"
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "XQuery"
    SPTQueryName = "XQuery"
    SQLString = "SELECT SQLUser.EP_VisitNumber.EPVIS_DebtorNumber_DR as HospitalNumber, SQLUser.EP_VisitNumber.EPVIS_GivenName as Forename, SQLUser.EP_VisitNumber.EPVIS_Surname as Surname, SQLUser.EP_VisitNumber.EPVIS_DateOfBirth as DOB, SQLUser.EP_VisitNumber.EPVIS_DoctorCode_DR->CTDR_Surname as CONS, SQLUser.EP_VisitNumber.EPVIS_VisitNumber as AccessionNumber, SQLUser.EP_VisitNumber.EPVIS_DateOfCollection as SampleReceivedDate, SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSet.VISTS_TestSet_DR->CTTS_Department_DR->CTDEP_NAME as LabDept FROM SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSet, SQLUser.EP_VisitNumber WHERE ( SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSet.VISTS_ParRef=SQLUser.EP_VisitNumber.EPVIS_VisitNumber  ) AND  ( SQLUser.EP_VisitTestSet.VISTS_ParRef  =  '1500000000')"
    ConnectString = "ODBC;DSN=DSNNAME;SERVER=IPADDRESS;PORT=1972;DATABASE=DATABASENAME;AUTHENTICATION METHOD=0;UID=USERNAME;PWD=PASSWORD;STATIC CURSORS=0;QUERY TIMEOUT=0;UNICODE SQLTYPES=0"
    Call CreateSPT(SPTQueryName, SQLString, ConnectString)

    'Me.[Hospital Number] = rec("HospitalNumber")
    Me.Refresh
    Me.[Hospital Number] = Null
    Me.[Hospital Number] = MyRS("HospitalNumber")

End If End Sub
```

My issue is I cannot populate the form with the results of the pass-through query.

Essentially, how do I declare the recordset so I can populate the form as Me.[Hospital Number] = MyRS("HospitalNumber") does not work as "MyRS" is function not defined.

Answer (score 0):

How do you have in mind these two statements should work together:

```
myquerydef.ReturnsRecords = False
Set MyRS = myquerydef.OpenRecordset()
```

You must have a query that returns records, then open a recordset from this, then pull a value from the recordset.

You declare MyRs in another function.
You must have something like:

```
MyRs = somequery.OpenRecordset()
Me![Hospital Number].Value = MyRs!HospitalNumber.Value
```

Comment: Good spot Gustav, I actually had '    myquerydef.ReturnsRecords = False' and 'myquerydef.ReturnsRecords = True', I've removed the "False" one, but still the same error.

Comment: So I've followed your advice as I understand it but I get "Variable not defined" on "XQuery", which is the query that is created  in the Sub     'MyRs = XQuery.OpenRecordset()' 'Me![Hospital Number].Value = MyRs!HospitalNumber.Value'